# How to prevent saving file with another filename?

Tags: vim

I'm often doing typo when I use `:w` command. For example: I do `:w a` command then a new file creating named 'a'.

How can I prevent parameters in `:w` (or `:wq`, `:wqa`) command? I want to use it to save current file with its name only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `autocommand` to check for possible wrong filenames you might type and avoid them. For example, to avoid filename `a`,

```
:autocmd BufWritePre a throw 'Forbidden file name: ' . expand('<afile>')
```

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun: You could use regex here

Comment: I think developing a habit of not doing `:w a` will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've defined the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> mappings for saving. As these work in most other applications, too, they are built into my muscle memory by now, and I hardly realize the regular saving. With that, I only use `:w otherfile` to write to a different name, or `:wq` for the final save-and-exit.

```
" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
nnoremap <C-S>      :<C-U>update<CR>
vnoremap <C-S>      :<C-U>update<CR>gv
inoremap <C-S>      <C-O>:update<CR>
```

Note: In the terminal, you may need to disable flow control commands (`stty start undef stop undef`) to avoid that `<C-S>` freezes the terminal.